# Get permutations of sub-arrays without changing order of sub-arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, generator, permutation

So my goal is to take in an arbitrary number strings as an array, sort them into sub-arrays of matching word-length, then permute each sub-array without changing the order of the sub-arrays and following these rules:

1. If any group has only one word, it is left as-is. (i.e. ['cat'])
2. Permute the first group until done.
3. Permute the second group once, then do step 1; only permuting the second group once each time step 1 is done.
4. Permute the third group once, then do step 2; only permuting the third group once each time step 2 is done.
5. Continue this pattern until all groups are done.

I've nearly been able to accomplish this, but I keep failing to get all permutations to come out. I've been struggling to figure it out for a while now, so I decided to look around a LOT and now I've come to ask for help. Here's what I've got so far (I apologize in advance for the strange variable names):

```
function* permute(permutation) {
  const length = permutation.length;
  let c = Array(length).fill(0),
    i = 1,
    k, p;

  yield permutation;
  while (i < length) {
    if (c[i] < i) {
      k = (i % 2) ? c[i] : 0;
      p = permutation[i];
      permutation[i] = permutation[k];
      permutation[k] = p;
      ++c[i];
      i = 1;
      yield permutation;
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }
}
function* permuteGroups(input) {
  input.sort((a,b) => {return a.length-b.length;});
  let groups = [], //Holds the list of Generators and words
      groupsCache = [], //Copy of groups to reset the Generators
      g = 0, i = input.length, len = input[i - 1].length,
      gid = 0, currentGroup, currentSet, finished = [];

  //Helper function to reset a Generator
  function reset(gid) {
    groups[gid] = {
      'currentValue': undefined,
      'nextValue': undefined,
      'generator': permute(groupsCache[gid].split(',')),
      'gen2': permute(groupsCache[gid].split(','))
    };
    groups[gid].nextValue = groups[gid].gen2.next().value.join(',');
  }
  function fetch(gid, next) {
    if (!!next) {
      if (groups[gid].generator === undefined) return { 'currentValue': groups[gid].currentValue, 'nextValue': undefined };
      let cv = groups[gid].generator.next();
      let nv = groups[gid].gen2.next();
      cv = (cv.done) ? 'done' : ((cv.value) ? cv.value.join(',') : undefined);
      nv = (nv.done) ? 'done' : ((nv.value) ? nv.value.join(',') : undefined);
      groups[gid].currentValue = cv;
      groups[gid].nextValue = nv;
    }
    let output = {
      'currentValue': groups[gid].currentValue,
      'nextValue': groups[gid].nextValue
    };
    return output;
  }
  function getOutput(next) {
    let gid = 0, len = groups.length, output = [];
    while (gid < len) {
      output.push(fetch(gid++, next).currentValue);
    }
    return output;
  }

  //First move words into sub-arrays based on length
  groups.push([]);
  while (i--) {
    if (input[i].length == len) {
      groups[g].push(input[i]);
      continue;
    }
    groups[++g] = [input[i]];
    len = input[i].length;
  }
  groupsCache = groups.map(x => x.join(',')); // Convert each group into a string to preserve order
  //Turn the sub-arrays into Generators if they have more than one item
  len = groups.length - 1;
  while (i++ < len) {
    groups[i] = (groups[i].length > 1) ? { 'currentValue': undefined, 'nextValue': undefined, 'generator': permute(groups[i].toString().split(',')), 'gen2': permute(groups[i].toString().split(',')) } : { 'currentValue': groups[i].toString().split(','), 'nextValue': undefined, 'generator': undefined, 'gen2': undefined };
    if (groups[i].gen2) groups[i].nextValue = groups[i].gen2.next().value.join(',');
    finished[i] = (groups[i].nextValue) ? false : true;
  }
  //console.log(finished)

  //Yield initial output
  yield getOutput(true);

  let index = 0, isNotDone = true, isInc = false;
  while (isNotDone) {
    // If we're supposed to be going up to the next group, but there isn't one, reset the index back to zero
    // Fetch the next value for the current group...
    currentSet = fetch(index, true);
    /* default, default, default
     / "rabbit,beaver,calf,wolf,cat,fox,dog"
     * Flip [0], default, default
     / "beaver,rabbit,calf,wolf,cat,fox,dog"
     * Reset [0], flip [1], default
     / "rabbit,beaver,wolf,calf,cat,fox,dog"
     * Flip [0], flipped, default
     / "beaver,rabbit,wolf,calf,cat,fox,dog"
     * Reset [0], Reset [1], move [3]
     / "rabbit,beaver,calf,wolf,fox,cat,dog"
    */
    // and yield it.
    yield getOutput();
    // If this was the last value before this group is done...
    if (currentSet.nextValue == 'done') {
//       if (!groups[index+1] || finished.slice(index+1).every(x => x === true)) {
//         finished[index] = true;
//         console.log(finished)
//         if (finished.every(x => x === true)) {
//           isNotDone = false;
//         }
//         index = 0;
//         continue;
//       }
      // reset the current group
      reset(index);
      // and put it back on the first value
      fetch(index, true);
      // Move on to the next group
      index++;
      // Mark that we plan on going to the next group up
      isInc = true;
      continue;
    }
    // Otherwise if it is not the last value and the isInc flag is set
    if (isInc) {
      // Reset the index back to zero
      index = 0;
      isInc = false;
    }
  }
  return 'done';
}
let perm = permuteGroups(['dog','fox','cat','wolf','calf','beaver','rabbit']);
let result = perm.next();
while (!result.done) {
  console.log(result.value.toString());
  result = perm.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a break from it for a while, I managed to get it to work as desired. Here's the end result for anyone in the future. It can be shoved into a Codepen as-is and will start working, but I suggest using a smaller list of words or it'll hang after a good while of filling up your console. I'm just leaving my example list to show what it can handle.

The main problem with my first approach was trying to look ahead to process if we need to step up to the next group, when a single generator worked just fine.

```
function* permute(permutation) {
  const length = permutation.length;
  let c = Array(length).fill(0),
    i = 1, k;

  yield permutation;
  while (i < length) {
    if (c[i] < i) {
      k = (i % 2) ? c[i] : 0;
      [permutation[i], permutation[k]] = [permutation[k], permutation[i]];
      ++c[i];
      i = 1;
      yield permutation;
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }
}

function* permuteGroups(input) {
  input.sort((a,b) => {return a.length-b.length;});
  let groups = [], //Holds the list of Generators and words
      groupsCache = [], //Copy of groups to reset the Generators
      g = 0, i = input.length, len = input[i - 1].length,
      gid = 0, currentGroup, currentSet;

  //Helper function to reset a Generator
  function reset(gid) {
    groups[gid] = {
      'currentValue': undefined,
      'generator': permute(groupsCache[gid].split(','))
    };
  }
  function fetch(gid, next) {
    let group = groups[gid];

    // IF next and next === true
    if (!!next) {
      if (group.generator === undefined) return { 'currentValue': group.currentValue };

      let cv = group.generator.next();
      group.currentValue = (cv.done ? 'done' : (cv.value ? cv.value.join(',') : undefined));
    }

    return {
      'currentValue': group.currentValue
    };
  }
  function getOutput(next) {
    return groups.map((group, index) => fetch(index, next).currentValue);
  }

  //First move words into sub-arrays based on length
  groups.push([]);
  while (i--) {
    if (input[i].length == len) {
      groups[g].push(input[i]);
      continue;
    }
    groups[++g] = [input[i]];
    len = input[i].length;
  }
  groupsCache = groups.map(x => x.join(',')); // Convert each group into a string to preserve order
  //Turn the sub-arrays into Generators if they have more than one item
  groups = groups.map(group => (group.length > 1 ? { 'currentValue': undefined, 'generator': permute(group.toString().split(',')) } : { 'currentValue': group.toString().split(','), 'generator': undefined }) );
  //Yield initial output
  yield getOutput(true);

  let index = 0, isInc = false;
  while (true) {
    // If we're supposed to be going up to the next group, but there isn't one, reset the index back to zero
    // Fetch the next value for the current group...
    currentSet = fetch(index, true);
    // If this was the last value before this group is done...
    if (currentSet.currentValue == 'done' || Array.isArray(currentSet.currentValue)) {
      // reset the current group
      reset(index);
      // and put it back on the first value
      fetch(index, true);
      // Move on to the next group
      index++;
      if (index === groups.length) {
          // We're done!
          return;
      }
      // Mark that we plan on going to the next group up
      isInc = true;
      continue;
    }
    // and yield it.
    yield getOutput();
    // Otherwise if it is not the last value and the isInc flag is set
    if (isInc) {
      // Reset the index back to zero
      index = 0;
      isInc = false;
    }
  }
}
// "yourself","hero","entire","blank","peg","usage","tot","debate","volt","lie","almond","baseball","sell","youngster","use","atom","left","sit","even","input","only","freight"
let perm = permuteGroups(["yourself","hero","entire","blank","peg","usage","tot","debate","volt","lie","almond","baseball","sell","youngster","use","atom","left","sit","even","input","only","freight"]), i = 1;
let result = perm.next();
while (!result.done) {
  console.log(i++, result.value.toString());
  result = perm.next();
}
```